# Name of array as pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers, char, integer

I learned that name of array is functioned as pointer. 
In C++, when I made integer type array name 'a', cout a  prints out the address of array.
But when I made char type array name 's', cout s  prints out the contents of array not address.
I want to know why these happens.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // a string is a sequence of characters.
    char s[4] = "abc"; // why not giving 3 as the size of the array?

    // what if you want to print the address?
    cout << '\n';
    cout << (void*) s << "\n"; // Treat 's' as a void* variable.
    cout<<(void*)&s<<endl;
    cout << (void*)&s[0] << "\n"; // This also works.
    cout << (void*)&s[1] << "\n";
    cout<endl;


    cout << s << "\n"; // Treat 's' as a void* variable.
    cout<<&s<<endl;
    cout << &s[0] << "\n"; // This also works.
    cout << &s[1] << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think that `cout` uses a template function which treats `char` arrays differently.

Comment: As to your question of "why not giving 3 as the size of the array" - it's because the length of the null-terminated string `"abc"` is 4 characters (the preprocessor adds a null character implictly).

Comment: And by the way, for a statically-declared array `x` (i.e., with its size specified as a constant), the values of `x` and `&x` are technically identical (same memory address).

Answer (score 0):

1.Always string constant end up with a null('\0') value.
    If you don't want this Null value, you can assign value Like this below

> char s1[3] = {'a','b','c'};

2.Above statement you are doing explicit typecasting!
    You are converting char array into void pointer. 
    And WKT, char has the size of 1.So the address was incremented
    be one. And FYI, Notaion of array name such as 's' is equals to
    &s[0].(Address of the First Index) and its also equals to address
    of the array name (&s)..

> [s == &s == &s[0]]

3. And We know that, A void pointer can hold address of any type and can be typcasted to any type.But when converting character into void pointer, we only see the address conversion. Because &s and s only holds the address of the first character. As well as, cout does not recongnizes that the value is character value.